# Implementing cutoff at a certain depth in a DFS

Tags: java, search, depth-first-search

I have this code and i want to implement a limit to the depth, how can i implement that here? Could i store the current depth somehow and compare it with the given limit? If so, how can i do that?
Thanks.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;


interface GoalFunction<T>
{
    boolean evaluate(Vertex<T> o);
}

public class Vertex<T>
{

    private final T data;
    private final List<Vertex<T>> _successors = new ArrayList<Vertex<T>>();

    Vertex(T data) { this.data = data; }
    T getData() { return data; }
    List<Vertex<T>> successors() { return _successors; }

    public static <T> boolean depthFirstSearch(Vertex<T> start,
                                               GoalFunction<T> isGoal,
                                               Stack<Vertex<T>> result)
    {
        if (result.contains(start))
    {
        return false;
    }

        result.push(start);

        if (isGoal.evaluate(start))
    {
        return true;
    }
        for (Vertex<T> v : start.successors()) {
        if (depthFirstSearch(v, isGoal, result))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

        // No path was found
        result.pop();
        return false; 
    }

    public static List<Vertex<Integer>> petersenGraph()
    {
        List<Vertex<Integer>> v = new ArrayList<Vertex<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            v.add(new Vertex<Integer>(i));
        }
        int[][] edges =
        {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,2}, {2,1}, {2,3}, {3,2}, {3,4}, {4,3}, {4,0}, {0,4},
         {5,6}, {6,5}, {6,7}, {7,6}, {7,8}, {8,7}, {8,9}, {9,8}, {9,5}, {5,9},
         {5,0}, {0,5}, {6,2}, {2,6}, {7,4}, {4,7}, {8,1}, {1,8}, {9,3}, {3,9}};
    for (int[] e : edges)
    {
        v.get(e[0]).successors().add(v.get(e[1]));
    }

        return v;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Vertex<Integer>> v = petersenGraph();
        Stack<Vertex<Integer>> path = new Stack<Vertex<Integer>>();
        if (depthFirstSearch(v.get(0), new GoalFunction<Integer>() {
            public boolean evaluate(Vertex<Integer> v)
            {
                return v.getData() == 7;
            }
        }, path))
        {
            System.out.print("Found path: ");
            for (Vertex<Integer> u : path)
            {
                System.out.print(u.getData() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No path found");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reimplement your DFS using recursion. Pass the incrementing value to the recursive function of the DFS:

```
   void recursive(int depth, .. parameters) {
     if (depth > CUT_OFF)
       return;
     ..        
     recursive(depth+1, parameters1);
     recursive(depth+1, parameters2);
   }
```

Then you are aware about the current depth and can break it at any level.

Comment: If works, could you accept this answer? Click on the V letter below the score.